# Angular ui-router cannot GET/

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Generated from yeoman angular ui-router application i have a state -

```js
$stateProvider
.state('exampleLink', {
        url         : '/exampleLink?photo=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/trafficnow/439dcc60-303b-457e-940a-6308d9f0ee5f/9d12687c-7d09-4f63-afd3-b4abd0d03aaf.jpg',
        templateUrl : 'views/someTemplate.html',
        controller  : 'SomeCtrl'
});
```

and a controller

```js
angular.module('App')
  .controller('SomeCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams) {
    $scope.obj = {
      photo : $stateParams.photo,
    };

  });
```

After adding `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` in the config and `<base href="/">` in my index file to active HTML5 mood, it gives me the following error. 
`Cannot GET /sharedLink?photo=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/trafficnow/439dcc60-303b-457e-940a-6308d9f0ee5f/9d12687c-7d09-4f63-afd3-b4abd0d03aaf.jpg`

Comment: I get error "AllAccessDisabled" when goto your image url

Comment: Yes, because the AWS Bucket is not public.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing a closing quotation mark at the end of your `url` property. Try replacing the first code snippet with this:

```
$stateProvider
.state('exampleLink', {
        url         : '/exampleLink?photo=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/trafficnow/439dcc60-303b-457e-940a-6308d9f0ee5f/9d12687c-7d09-4f63-afd3-b4abd0d03aaf.jpg',
        templateUrl : 'views/someTemplate.html',
        controller  : 'SomeCtrl'
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the issue. The url params can't fetch the special character like ". ( - _ " etc.

Comment: Glad you figured it out - you should be able to URL encode your params for example `-` should be replaced with `%2D` and `.` as `'%2E`.

For a full list of URL encoded characters you can read more here - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: it works from `<a ui-sref="exampleLink({photo : 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/trafficnow/439dcc60-303b-457e-940a-6308d9f0ee5f/9d12687c-7d09-4f63-afd3-b4abd0d03aaf.jpg'})">click</a>`
But when i reload/refresh the page from the browser, it provides me the same error. is there any solution...??